# wifi client and wifi host together on an openwrt router

Tags: wireless-networking

I have read that openwrt can have two wifi networks on the same router.  Is it possible to configure one network as a host and the other as a client?  The only internet I have access to is on my cell phone and I would like to somehow connect it to my network.  If there is no other way, I will open up the router and add USB ports to it and tether that way, but my original question is the way I would prefer to do it.

Answer (score 0):

It it not possible to configure 1 as a host and another as a client assuming that you only have 1 radio.

If you have a dual band system, you should be able to use 1 band as a client and the other as a host.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like what you're asking for is to turn your router into a signal repeater for your cell phone hotspot.

There are many tutorials demonstrating this process, and it is the same concept as "increasing your range" using two routers.

I see you are using openwrt, but here is a guide with ddwrt. http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Repeater_Bridge